# Is there a simpler way to express the fraction $\frac{x}{x+y}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can I simplify this expression, perhaps into two expressions $\frac{x}{x+y}$ or is that already simplified as much as possible?

Comment: Simplification usually has a particular *purpose*. A simplification that is optimal for one purpose may be non-optimal for another purpose.

Comment: Oddly, if you try to expand this expression using long division, then you end up with the series $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 ...$

Comment: @Sean Mill: If you got the answer, please determine it by clicking on Tick sign. (I've another one but I'm in doubt to say!)

Comment: Hi @Sean Mill , don't hesitate to post your answer . We shall learn from all the answers .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simplified as much as possible, though sometimes it's more convenient to write it as

$$\frac{x+y-y}{x+y}=1-\frac{y}{x+y}\;.$$

Answer (score 7):

**Form 1**: way of giving as sum of 2 quantities
$$  \frac{x+y -y}{x+y} = 1 - \frac{y}{x+y} $$

**Form 2** : express as bringing x to denominator , to see expression in terms of  y divided by x 
$$ \displaystyle\frac{1}{1 + \displaystyle\frac{y}{x}} $$

**Form 3** :
take y out , so that you can view the expression in terms of only x divided by y

$$ \frac{\displaystyle\frac{x}{y}}{\displaystyle\frac{x}{y} + 1 } $$

Answer (score 3):

You might want
$$\frac{x}{x+y}=\frac{(x+y)-y}{x+y}=1-\frac{y}{x+y}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The given expression uses two operations (one division and one addition). If we judge simplicity by the number of operations, only an expression with one operation would be simpler, but the expression equals none of $x+y$, $x-y$, $y-x$, $xy$, $\frac xy$, $\frac yx$.